# Составить программу табулирования функции у = f (x) У меня почемуто вечний цикл?

Tags: c++, c

Составить программу таблирования функции у = f (x) на интервале [a; b]
с шагом h ровно (b-a)/N, где N это целое число (вводится с клавиатуры).
Велечини которие нужно найти ето суммы y>-0.1 и y<-0.1
Я пробивал сам написать вот код но не получается я не очень понял задание и у меня вечний цикл пишет что число nan.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    int n;
    int b = 1;
    float a = 0.5;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    float h = (b - a) / n;
    for (int i = a; i < b; i += h)
    {
        float y = x / asin(x);
        printf("%f", y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Чтоб найти h=(b-a)/N

Answer (score 0):

```
  float h=(b-a)/n;
  for(int i=a;i<b; i+=h){
      float y=x/asin(x);
      printf("%f",y);
  }
```

начну с мелочи - в таких вещах точнее (лучше) идти с целочисленным шагом от 0 до `n`, чем каждый раз добавлять смещение к позиции и идти от границы `a` к границе `b` - точность меньше страдает, т.е.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const float x = a + i * (b - a) / (n - 1)
}
```

теперь по ошибкам:

1. где в вашем коде вы в цикле вычисляете `x`, по которому потом вычисляете `y`?
2. вы в цикле идете от границы `a` к `b`, но не с помощью числа с плавающей запятой, а целочисленного числа!!!

   ```
    for(int i=a;i<b; i+=h){
   ```

надо тогда править на

```
    for(float i=a;i<b; i+=h){
```

Результат (значение только произвольные поставил):

```
int main()
{
    // получить кол-во точек в графике
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    // проанализировать данные
    const float a = 0;
    const float b = 10;

    const float sum = 0;

    for(int index = 0; index < n; index ++){
        // определить значение координаты x
        const float x = a + index * (b - a) / (n - 1)

        // определить значение координаты y
        const float y = x / asin(x);

        // подсчитать сумму значений в заданном диапазоне
        if ((y >= 0) && (y <= 5))
            sum += y;

        // вычислить результаты на экран
        printf("%f", y);
    }

    // вывести на экран сумму
    printf("%f", sum);
}
```

Comment: @nerv1, с построением таблицы я задачу понял - объяснения я привел, а вторая часть - это что? не понял, что именно надо сделать?

Comment: @nerv1, вы все свалили в одну кучу и считаете, что это должно работать? это же код, а не салат. Добавил в ответ код поизучать - только цифры другие (ставил от балды)

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/rkxj771OD должно бить верно ?

Comment: @nerv1, нет, приведённый код неверен - у вас вложенный цикл и вообще там треш получается - проще стереть все и написать заново.. аккуратно - опять таки - посмотрите код в моем ответе - так должно выглядеть

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/Hy4Lw7JuP вот я скопировал польностю ваш код даже поставил там условие где ви пропустили закритие я вставил код почему там значения 10 и 5 ? Он не считает он нерабочей